# WIndows Azure FTP: How to get notified when a file is uploaded?

Tags: azure, ftp, filesystemwatcher

On my own server, I have a Windows Service to monitor (using the FileSystemWatcher) a FTP folder, whenever a file is uploaded to that folder, it will be processed right away.

Now I want to move everything to Windows Azure, is it possible to install my Windows Service on the Azure server and monitor the FTP folder on the Azure server?

If it's possible, how should I do it?

If not, what's the alternatives? I just want to be notified when a file is uploaded and do some processing on the file automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Virtual Machines, then the process of installing a service is equivalent to what you'd do with your on-premises server: Just RDP into your server and install the service.

If you're using a web/worker role, you'll need to launch the service installer from a startup script with elevated privileges.